# How to generate correct url for window.location.href?

Tags: javascript

How to generate correct url for window.location.href in the following two scenarios:

1. current url is http://example.com:8080/something/
2. current url is http://example.com:8080/something/something-else/

target url is http://example.com:8080/something/something-new/.

Ideally I would like to have the same code for both scenarios and http://example.com:8080/something/ should not be hardcoded.

Comment: What is your question and what are you trying to do?  `window.location.href` is the URL of the current page.  If you change it, it will load a new page.

Comment: You may consider sending the root URL from the server by inject it into the javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't without somehow hardcoding (or softcoding) the path. You will need a root path, to know how many directories you need to go up (either 0 or 1) before you can add `something-new` to the path. If you got a server side scripting language, you can calculate it or define it in a setting, and then output the path so it's available in Javascript.

Comment: What if I use separate code for scenario 1 and 2? For scenario 1 currently I use `window.location.href = 'something-else'+'/';`

Comment: Yes, that's possible. For scenario2 you could use `window.location.href = '../something-else/'`

Answer (score 0):

Could you do:

```
window.location.href="/something/something-new/";
```